# Calculate and show LBP histogram in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, lbph-algorithm

I want to create a real-time emotion recognition program using LBP and SVM. After face-detection process, I converted my captured image into 32x32 pixels grayscale image.
I am struggled in creating and showing histogram for my LBP (I use simple, uninterpolated LBP). What I got so far is showing resulting LBP images real-time.

Ahonen et. al's paper states that

> divide the LBP image into m local regions and extract a histogram from each (region)

How do we decide number of m local regions ?

I have been trying to look for answers 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733448/how-to-calculate-local-binary-pattern-histograms-with-opencv), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581267/uniform-circular-lbp-face-recognition-implementation) but I couldn't make sense out of it. I saw berak's work here regarding spatial histogram and I am still confused. Can someone please teach me step-by-step (yes, I am a newbie :/). I really need to calculate and show the histogram like shown on page 14 [here](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780857297471-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1153741-p174122174).

Probably I should show my messy code here.

```
// Libraries included
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// Namespace declaration
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Function Headers
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);
Mat LBP(Mat img);

// Global variables
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;


// Function main
int main(){
    // Start cvStartWindowThread to create a thread process. VERY IMPORTANT
    cvStartWindowThread();

    // Initializing local variables
    int k=1;
    CvCapture* capture;
    Mat frame;

    // Load the cascade, use ifs (if more than one xml files are used) to prevent segmentation fault
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)){
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return -1;
    };

    // Start the program, capture from CAM with CAMID =0    
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0 );
    if( capture !=0){   
        while(k==1){
            frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            cv::flip(frame,frame,1);
            //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
            if( !frame.empty() ){
                detectAndDisplay( frame );
            }
            else{
                printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
                break;
            }
            int c = waitKey(1);
            if( (char)c == 'c' ) {
                k=0;
                destroyWindow("FYP Live Camera");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("CvCaptureFromCAM ERROR\n");
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}

// Function detectAndDisplay
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame){
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat crop;
    Mat crop2;
    Mat res;
    Mat gray;
    Mat dst;
    string text;
    stringstream sstm;


    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    // Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 4, 0 | CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, Size(60, 60));

    // Set Region of Interest
    cv::Rect roi_b;
    cv::Rect roi_c;

    size_t ic = 0; // ic is index of current element


    if (faces.size() !=0){
        for (ic = 0; ic < faces.size(); ic++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)
        {
            roi_b.x = faces[ic].x;
            roi_b.y = faces[ic].y;
            roi_b.width = faces[ic].width;
            roi_b.height = faces[ic].height;

            crop = frame(roi_b);
            resize(crop, res, Size(256, 256), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images

            cvtColor(res, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert cropped image to Grayscale

            eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, eyes, 1.1, 4, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(15, 15) );
            if (eyes.size() == 2){
                if ( eyes[0].x <= eyes[1].x ){
                    roi_c.x = eyes[0].x*0.75;
                    roi_c.y = eyes[0].y*0.7;
                    roi_c.width = (eyes[1].x+65)-roi_c.x;
                    roi_c.height = 190;
                }
                else if ( eyes[0].x >= eyes[1].x ) {
                    roi_c.x = eyes[1].x*0.75;
                    roi_c.y = eyes[1].y*0.7;
                    roi_c.width = (eyes[0].x+65)-roi_c.x;
                    roi_c.height = 190;
                }
                crop2 = gray(roi_c);
                resize(crop2, crop2, Size(128, 128), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images

                dst= LBP(crop2);

                Point centerEye1( eyes[0].x + eyes[0].width*0.5, eyes[0].y + eyes[0].height*0.5 );
                int radiusEye1 = cvRound( (eyes[0].width + eyes[0].height)*0.25 );
                circle( gray, centerEye1, radiusEye1, Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 1, 8, 0 );

                Point centerEye2( eyes[1].x + eyes[1].width*0.5, eyes[1].y + eyes[1].height*0.5 );
                int radiusEye2 = cvRound( (eyes[1].width + eyes[1].height)*0.25 );
                circle( gray, centerEye2, radiusEye2, Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 1, 8, 0 );

            }

            Point pt1(faces[ic].x, faces[ic].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
            Point pt2((faces[ic].x + faces[ic].height), (faces[ic].y + faces[ic].width));
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
            putText(frame, "Auto-focused", cvPoint((faces[ic].x+faces[ic].width/4), faces[ic].y-10), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
        }

    }


    imshow("Live Camera", frame);
    if (!crop2.empty())
    {
        imshow("Gray2", dst);
        imshow("Gray3", crop2);
    }
    else{
        destroyWindow("Gray2");
        destroyWindow("Gray3");
    }   
}
Mat LBP(Mat img){
    Mat dst = Mat::zeros(img.rows-2, img.cols-2, CV_8UC1);
    for(int i=1;i<img.rows-1;i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<img.cols-1;j++) {
            uchar center = img.at<uchar>(i,j);
            unsigned char code = 0;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1)) > center) << 7;
                code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i-1,j)) > center) << 6;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i-1,j+1)) > center) << 5;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i,j+1)) > center) << 4;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i+1,j+1)) > center) << 3;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i+1,j)) > center) << 2;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i+1,j-1)) > center) << 1;
            code |= ((img.at<uchar>(i,j-1)) > center) << 0;
            dst.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1) = code;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Apparently I cannot post my screenshot since I dont have enough reputation points :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly what you're computing is just the LBP pattern, not the histogram - for which you need to create an array of bins and generate the histogram of the LBP feature.
In bytefish's code, if you look into the github you'll also find code to generate the histogram with 59 bins.

Comment: Well, I wasn't criticizing, just explaining what he needed to do and what he had done. Here is something that can be done:
http://pi-virtualworld.blogspot.dk/2014/03/uniform-lbp-features-and-spatial.html

Comment: Looked into it, and it really helps. Thanks to both of you :D cheers